# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'eshop.sessions' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, database

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'eshop.sessions' doesn't exist
SELECT * FROM `sessions` WHERE `id` = N7H5CpGFStKcjjHhlq9aOo05OE0eU2I9muBXC4Tc limit 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH5Ym.png)

1. When i check my database i have no table named sessions (never had by the way)
2. I deleted the foder Migrations, Seeders, Factories and started again but no results
3. I did all these commandes with no results
   php artisan config:cache
   php artisan config:clear
   and composer dump-autoload -o
   php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
   php artisan migrate

Comment: I'm new here and my English is not my native language, if you can help me that would be nice, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 11 you need to have a session table migration for this you can use the artisan comand

```
php artisan make:session-table
```

After:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 11 and do not have sessions migration in your create_users_table migration file, you will have to manually add it.
[This](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/441845d88dfc2a4fbf59f1e57d48889c8de664bb/database/migrations/0001_01_01_000000_create_users_table.php) is currently the latest migration file for laravel 11.x and inside you can find Schema for missing table

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the session driver in .env file.
Laravel 11 by default has *SESSION_DRIVER=database*

if you don't want to use this, change it to another driver like
*SESSION_DRIVER=file*